# Regression basics questions R

Tags: r, regression

I was doing some simple linear reg in R and I ran across an interesting case.

I did

```
model1 = lm(y~x1, data)
model2 = lm(y~x2, data)
model3 = lm(y~x1+x2, data)
```

I got R^2 values from model1, model2 and model3 BUT is there anyway (mathematically) that I can get model3 R^2 from the R^2 values of model1 and model2 ? I think something to do with RSS1 and RSS2 and maybe covariance, but not sure.

Thanks

Comment: This is a stats question, so I've flagged it for migration to our sibling site, Cross Validated.

Comment: Generate a new model that is made of model1 and model2. But I think the OP is asking about how to generate such a model in R.

Comment: the answer is yes, but i can't think of a situation where you'd know enough information to answer your question _without_ also being able to give the results of the second model (the key is covariances like you said)

Comment: Sure. You can compute the estimate y for each x in model 1 and then repeat for model 2. Once you have the new values combine them in a single data column. You just have to predict model 3 based on the model 1 and 2 estimates (as a single data column). However, you loose fidelity and will most likely end up having a poorer fit than the original data points, unless you have a strong theoretical case that the models better reflect reality than your data. Remember to report the adjusted R^2s when comparing models.

Answer (score 1):

As wikipedia tells us the [coefficient of determination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination) as 1 minus the ratio of the explained sum of squares of the model over the total sum of squares of the sample we use this model upon. Or with some hand-waving: 1 minus the explain over total variance in your modelling.

Now as you correctly identify your `model1`, `model2` and `model3` are closely related and one should be able to combine the resulting RSS from `model1` and `model2` and get the RSS of `model3`. (The other parts of the $R^2$ are the same).

So let's see what can we get out of the box:

```
 set.seed(123)
 N = 123
 data = data.frame(x1 = runif(N), x2=  runif(N ));
 data$y = data$x1 + data$x2 + rnorm(N);

 model1 = lm(y~x1, data)
 model2 = lm(y~x2, data)
 model3 = lm(y~x1+x2, data)
```

And lets check if our intuition is correct:

```
 1 - sum(( data$y - fitted(model1))^2) / 
     sum((data$y - mean(data$y))^2) - summary(model1)$r.squared
 #  -1.457168e-16
 1 - sum(( data$y - fitted(model2))^2) / 
     sum((data$y - mean(data$y))^2) - summary(model2)$r.squared
 #  -1.110223e-16
 1 - sum(( data$y - fitted(model3))^2) / 
     sum((data$y - mean(data$y))^2) - summary(model3)$r.squared
 # -4.163336e-17
```

All these guys evaluate to numerical zeros so we are pretty confident we got out basic definition right (or at least aligning with `R`'s definition.) Now we mentioned we want the RSS of `model1` and `model2` to get as close as possible to the RSS of `model3`. Let's remember that the RSS is essentially the sum of squared differences of the original values from predicted sample mean plus the predicted individual variations (ie. RSS = $\sum( y_i - \hat{y}_i)^2$ where $\hat{y}_i = \hat{\mu} + x_i\hat{\beta}$. So actually if we want the fitted values of `model3` we have: $\hat{y}_{i,m3} = \hat{\mu}_{m3} + x_{1,i}\hat{\beta}_{1,m3} + x_{2,i}\hat{\beta}_{2,m3}$; where  $\hat{y}_{i,m3}$ is the $i$-th predicted value from `model3`, $\hat{\mu}_{m3}$ is the estimated sample mean value from `model3` and $\hat{\beta}_{2,m3}$ is the estimated $\beta$ coefficient for variable `x2` from `model3`. 
Similarly for your example for `model1`'s fitted values we will have  $\hat{y}_{i,m1} = \hat{\mu}_{m1} + x_{1,i}\hat{\beta}_{1,m1}$ and for `model2`  $\hat{y}_{i,m2} = \hat{\mu}_{m2} + x_{2,i}\hat{\beta}_{2,m2}$.
So if we blindly say that $\hat{y}_{i,m3} = \hat{y}_{i,m1} +\hat{y}_{i,m2}$ we will clearly are about an estimated $\hat{\mu}$ off. So the obvious thing is to just add a $\hat{\mu}$. ie.

```
1 - sum(( data$y + mean(data$y) - fitted(model2) - fitted(model1) )^2) /  
    sum(  (data$y - mean(data$y))^2) - summary(model3)$r.squared 
# -3.320282e-06
# (Discrepancy? Check covariance.)
```

Hm... This definitely close enough to suggest we are on the right track but not close enough to say we got right down to standard numerical precision. The catch here is in the covariance between the `x1` and `x2`; this is the only bit information that while present in `model3` is not present in `model1` or `model2`. We can remind ourselves that by remembering that using the simple OLS formula for the estimation of $\beta$, can be written as:
\begin{align}
\hat{\beta} = \frac{\hat{cov}(y,x)}{\hat{var}(x)}.
\end{align}
and in the same manner if you have multiple predictors, say `x1` and `x2` you would write:
\begin{align}
\hat{\beta} =  \hat{cov}(y,[x_1 x_2])^{-1}\hat{var}([x_1 x_2]).
\end{align}
Clearly now if there is any covariance between `x1` and `x2` that will come into play and it will change our estimates. Is there any?

```
  cov(data[,1:2])[2]
  # [1] -0.0004360986
```

Yeap, it exists. Nothing huge, but something is there. OK, so what if we had independent variables? Well, let's see that. I will use [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) to get the principal components scores of our sample and use those as surrogate data for a new dataset.

```
 PCScores = princomp(data[,1:2])$scores

 cov(PCScores)[2]
 [1] -4.890018e-19 # Nice numerical zero

 newdata = data.frame(x1 = PCScores[,1], x2 = PCScores[,2]);
 newdata$y = newdata$x1 + newdata$x2 + rnorm(N);

 model1 = lm(y~x1, newdata)
 model2 = lm(y~x2, newdata)
 model3 = lm(y~x1+x2, newdata)

 1 - sum(( newdata$y - fitted(model1) )^2) / 
         sum( (newdata$y - mean(newdata$y))^2) - summary(model1)$r.squared
 #  8.326673e-17
 1 - sum(( newdata$y - fitted(model2) )^2) / 
         sum( (newdata$y - mean(newdata$y))^2) - summary(model2)$r.squared
 # -9.714451e-17
 1 - sum(( newdata$y - fitted(model3) )^2) / 
         sum( (newdata$y - mean(newdata$y))^2) - summary(model3)$r.squared
 # 2.775558e-17
```

So far so good what about our intuition about $\hat{\mu}$ though?

```
 1 - sum(( newdata$y + mean(newdata$y) - fitted(model2) - fitted(model1) )^2) / 
     sum(  (newdata$y - mean(newdata$y))^2) - summary(model3)$r.squared 
 # 2.775558e-17
```

Or mathematically:
\begin{align}
1 - \frac{\sum ( y_i + \hat{\mu}_y - \hat{y}_{i,m1} - \hat{y}_{i,m2})^2}{\sum ( y_i - \hat{\mu}_y)^2}
\end{align}

Which is now numerically correct. :) We have replicated exactly the RSS of `model3` using `model1` and `model2` because the explanatory variables in `model1` and `model2` are independent. Let me note that one might be tempted to somehow insert a covariance term in the calculation shown above. That is not really feasible because the presence of the covariance terms will render the estimates $\hat{y}_{i,m1}$ and $\hat{y}_{i,m2}$ suboptimal as they will be estimated without taking in account any covariance-based variation. In that case, yes, one will be able to an $R^2$ but it will be biased.